# Where was Cinderella during the events of Shrek?

Tags: shrek

The Magic Mirror presented Farquaad with 3 options for princesses to marry to become King, Snow White, Cinderella and Fiona.

Fiona was locked in the Dragon’s Keep (obviously) and Snow White was seen in Shrek’s swamp with the 7 Dwarves and the other fairytale creatures.

But where was Cinderella during this film? If Lord Farquaad chose her, where would he go get her?

Comment: Why would he send Shrek at all? He only held the tournament because he needed someone to rescue Fiona from the dragon-infested castle...

Comment: @Valorum I’ve edited it so it doesn’t say about Shrek getting her.

Comment: It says in the mirror scene that she's a "*mentally abused shut-in from a kingdom far, far away*" and that her hobbies include "*cooking and cleaning for her two evil sisters*". Is there any reason to assume she's not literally in Far Far Away?

Comment: If she WAS in Far Far Away, how did she make it to Shrek’s swamp from there in time for his wedding?

Comment: It's not clear how long after the events of the bulk of the film their wedding took place.

Comment: Interestingly, in both the script and the novelisation, she's identified (at the wedding) as Sleeping Beauty, not Cinderella

Comment: Really, huh? Well, if she WAS Sleeping Beauty, why didn’t she show up with her 3 fairies when the fairytale creatures were at the swamp at the beginning?

Comment: "FROM a kingdom, far far away" does not equal "from THE Kingdom of Far, Far Away" (is a stretch but...)

Comment: @NKCampbell - It's pretty clear that the Kingdom of Far Far Away was invented for the second film.

Comment: as I said @Valorum - it's a stretch. Though - Fiona is said to be FROM a dragon guarded castle, so the mirror is possibly merely indicating their present location. Also since Cinderella is indicated to be a princess, that would also imply that she is past her days as a put upon step-sister, and is no longer with her prince (otherwise Farquad would add home-wrecking to his nefariousness). Thus, she is not THE princess of Far Far Away as that would be Fiona, daughter of the King of FFA, so per what the mirrors says of Fiona, Cinderella is likely just IN FFA at that moment.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Far Far Away boast [many princesses](https://shrek.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Princesses). It's not really clear whether this title is because their respective fathers are kings/husbands are princes or whether it's an honorific of some sort.

Comment: @NKCampbell If she’s no longer with her Prince, does that make her a Princess DOWAGER?

Comment: Or would she even count as still a princess at all?