# Who was the Princess who tried to catch Fiona’s bouquet at the end of Shrek?

Tags: character-identification, shrek

Inspired by a comment on this question: [Where was Cinderella during the events of Shrek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246633/where-was-cinderella-during-the-events-of-shrek?noredirect=1#comment678140_246633)

The Shrek Wiki identified her as Cinderella, but apparently, the novelisation and script identified her as Sleeping Beauty.

But if she WAS Sleeping Beauty, why didn’t she show up with her 3 fairies and the other fairytale creatures at the beginning?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3bI7kbVBwM - You see her quite a few times in that scene. I rather think it's supposed to be Cinderella, noting the bright yellow dress.

Comment: is there a union rule that Sleeping Beauty always must make appearances w/ fairies and creatures?

Comment: OK. I've seen plenty of people referring to an interview (where the producers said that they considered Sleeping Beauty for the film, but removed her in favour of Cinderella because their characters are too similar) but I can't find the original source

Comment: Moving way, way, way down the canon, Cinderella was confirmed to be at the wedding in the "[guest list](https://live.staticflickr.com/5125/5368599197_7f421d5eec_b.jpg)" poster found outside the [Shrek 4D ride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=47&v=v7chJ1t9v-c&feature=youtu.be). I doubt that the makers of the films had anything to do with this though...

Comment: @Valorum Then why did you say on the earlier question that the script calls her Sleeping Beauty?

Comment: @AlexDowns - She was listed as Sleeping Beauty in the novelisation which, presumably, is based on the script. She was, however, not featured in the film.

Comment: Are you asking the title question or the question in the final paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the final movie, it's definitely Cinderella - you can see her in the earlier scene when the Magic Mirror is showing Lord Farquaad potential princesses to marry, and the mirror explicitly identifies her as Cinderella. Note that the hairstyle, clothing and face match (though the animation style is a little different in the mirror).

Comment: Then why did the novelisation call her Sleeping Beauty?